# Prevent JComboBox from filling in the field automatically

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a JComboBox that shows filtered suggestions based on the input from the user so far. Filtering the model works, but the default behaviour of the JComboBox is to automatically put the current value from the list into the textfield if you go through the list with the arrow keys.

As I'm filtering based on the content of the associated PlainDocument, navigating the ComboBox list with arrow keys triggers the filter as the content of the document is automatically changed. The `insertString` method doesn't distinguish between manual user input and the selection by the ComboBox itself.

I found the suggestion to set the `"JComboBox.isTableCellEditor"`property to true, which does seem to disable the automatic input, but it does seem to do more than that and breaks the usual behaviour in my case.

Is there a way to intercept the automatic insertion of the currently selected item into the Document? How can I distinguish between the real user input, and what the JComboBox inserts into the field automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off auto selection in combobox while navigating in dropdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260842/how-to-turn-off-auto-selection-in-combobox-while-navigating-in-dropdown)

Comment: Interesting that the answer cited by @Berger refers to a JCheckBox, not a JComboBox.